# Replacement of Zend_Barcode in Magento 2.3.x

Tags: magento2.3, magento2.3.2, zend-framework

I have upgraded my Magento from **Magento 2.2.7** to **Magento 2.3.2** version. In my custom module, I used:

**`\Zend_Barcode::factory()`** function, but as per https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/release-notes/backward-incompatible-changes/, the library **Zend_Barcode** has been removed.

Can anyone help me to find replacement of this library?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Zend_Barcode has not been removed, only upgraded.

You can use this class: \Zend\Barcode\Barcode.

Associated composer package => zendframework/zend-barcode

Best Regards

Comment: Thanks @Raf, Just got the same a few hours ago while digging into vendor directory. Anyway, +1 for the useful answer.